# python signifiance of the start line %%

Tags: python

I am seeing a lot of opensource python code. they have starting lines like:

```
%%writefile test/setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages
...
```

or

```
%%bash
rm -rf test
```

or

```
%%writefile test/trainer/problem.py
import os ...
```

what is %% signify

Comment: It's a `Linux` shell command. See [here](https://superuser.com/a/1119299) for more informations.

Comment: @ChihebNexus: No it's not. That's a completely unrelated syntax in a completely different language family (shell syntaxes), and the code here doesn't even match that syntax.

Answer (score 3):

That's not strictly Python. That's IPython [cell magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics) syntax. It has to be run in an environment that supports that syntax, such as an IPython prompt or a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Thank you yes it is in juniprt note book. what does it mean with that python file name

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only used in IPython, they call it "[magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)".